# Changing iFrame src with jQuery based on select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to display a photosphere in a div, with the src being based on a value from a select menu.

The select menu will offer different rooms the user can view, and the div will hold an iFrame which displays the photosphere.

Here's what I have so far - it's broken (I'll explain below):

```
<!-- SCRIPT FOR PHOTOSPHERE-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // SELECT MENU
            $("#mySelect").change(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();   

                //IFRAME TAG
                $("#myPhotoSphere").attr
                var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'photosphere_example.png')   
                $(this).attr('src', src);

                // Classroom:
                if(value == "1")
                { $("#myPhotoSphere").attr("src","http://orb.photo/embedded_player.php?view=201712011cb4f0e032532a59807bea088f9ca145"); }

                //Common room:
                if(value == "2")
                { $("#myPhotoSphere").attr("src","http://orb.photo/embedded_player.php?view=20171201a1da59af307b44fa6dfa5ab2dfc157bd"); }

                //Lecture theatre: 
                if(value == "3")
                { $("#myPhotoSphere").attr("src","http://orb.photo/embedded_player.php?view=2017120169fafbe2c0a507bbb06284857b3ea427"); }

                //Atrium:
                if(value == "4")
                { $("#myPhotoSphere").attr("src","http://orb.photo/embedded_player.php?view=20171201a5853f710927d4a6b13909117b9ac85a"); }

                //Coffe Shop:
                if(value == "5")
                { $("#myPhotoSphere").attr("src"," http://orb.photo/embedded_player.php?view=20171201b19318b56e5168ce54ee5a2cc024c798"); }
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Then here's the html:

```
 <!-- VIRTUAL TOUR -->
        <select id="mySelect">
            <option value ="" disabled selected> Select a PhotoSphere </option>

            <option value="1"> Computing Classroom </option>
            <option value="2"> Common Room </option>
            <option value="3"> Leacture Theatre </option>
            <option value="4"> Atrium </option>
            <option value="5"> Coffee Shop </option>
        </select>

        <div>
            <iframe id="myPhotoSphere" src="http://orb.photo/embedded_player.php?view=201712011cb4f0e032532a59807bea088f9ca145" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900" height="600">Please enable iframes to view content.</iframe>
        </div>
```

I'm not sure where to go on from here, I've been looking at how people use jQuery and change certain parts (which I've sort of puzzled together, however, I've hit a wall and can't seem to work it out).

Apologies for any embarrassing mistakes (newbie)..

Comment: Why not just set the `value` of your `option` tags to the URL you want to associate w/the option.  Then you only need one method to set the `src` equal to the selected value `onchange`.  You won't need all of those `if` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this to simplify it:

**HTML**

```
<!-- VIRTUAL TOUR -->
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" disabled selected> Select a PhotoSphere </option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</option>
  <option value="http://www.msn.com">MSN</option>
</select>

<div>
  <iframe id="myPhotoSphere" src="http://www.google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900" height="600"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // SELECT MENU
  $("#mySelect").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    //IFRAME TAG
    console.log(value);
    $("#myPhotoSphere").attr('src', value);
  })
});
```

Here's a working example (the links just load other jsfiddle versions of this example):
https://jsfiddle.net/j94geqt5/3/

Comment: That's a lot simpler than mine. However, it doesn't change the photosphere.

Comment: @Jordan, are you sure? Did you try my jsfiddle link? Note that JSFiddle is blocking requests to external sites, which is why my links in the example point only to other jsfiddle URLs.